# Better way to get the html source of a page

Tags: php

I'm trying to get some data on a web page by filtering its source code, I found lots of ways  for grabbing html content of a web page, like `$html = file_get_html('http://www.exam.com/results/');` , **curl**, **html get source**.

What's the best way to grab html source code of a page? Or are all those methods equal?

Comment: `$html = file_get_contents('http://www.exam.com/results/');`, then use a DOM parser to work with it.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ is good for parsing HTML

Comment: Roger that, thanks a lot for your answer @adeneo ...

Comment: @WingLeong : I'll check that, thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cURL may provide better preformance than `file_get_contents($url)` *****.
I'd rather use cURL becuase all those functions finally retrieve a certain webpage contents, the only difference is the runtime which as I said is better when using cURL.

*You could find a decent (and yet not formal) proof including a benchmark right here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance

Comment: Please provide some evidence to back up your claim.

Comment: I've tested performance more than once , and cURL does provide better runtime. You probably know that such functions runtime is measured in ms ( depends on mass of content on the desired webpage ) , but cURL usually does it faster.

Comment: Please provide some evidence to back up your claim.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance

Comment: Thank you. Please edit this evidence into your answer so that your answer stands alone as a piece of fact-backed reasoning.

Comment: @itamar :im already using curl to post values and get back the source, but i have no idea about filtering html elements with curl

Comment: I have worked with html dom phrase but none with curl

Comment: I don't think I get you right , do you want to filter all html elements from the content you get , or get specific tags ?

Comment: no I just want to filter javascript tags in the page source and get data inside the javascript code..

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you need, but it is important to remember that `curl` will return the response as text while `file_get_html` will return a `Simple_HTML_DOM`. Also I think it important to note that `file_get_html` calls `file_get_contents` under the hood.

Personally, I have a mild preference for loading the data into memory first (I find it easier to debug), but I generally dislike using `curl_*` unless I need to send out some sort of headers with the request (POST variables or `WWW-Auth` header, etc). For everything else I find that it turns a one line function call into a hot mess. So I generally rely on `file_get_contents`.

As to `Simple_HTML_DOM`, I wonder if it could possibly be faster than the PHP native compiled libraries. You can access these using [`simplexml_load_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) or [`DomDocument::loadHTMLFile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php).

Answer (score 1):

cURL provides significantly more control, as @itamar suggested. It allows you to set a few things you cannot set using file_get_contents, including:

- Proxy usage
- Headers
- Permanent cookie storage

And it also allows you to retrieve headers.

cURL usage is rather complicated, but the payoff is quite nice. Advice is to wrap it in a function. I tend to use this:

```
protected static function prepare_channel(Request $r) {
    $r->channel = curl_init();
    $p = array();
    foreach ($r->GET as $k => $v) {
        $p[] = $k."=".$v;
    }
    $head = array();
    foreach ($r->getHeaders() as $k => $v) {
        $head[] = $k.": ".$v;
    }
    curl_setopt($r->channel, CURLOPT_URL, $r->getURI()."?".implode("&",$p));
    curl_setopt($r->channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $head);
    curl_setopt($r->channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($r->channel, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
    curl_setopt($r->channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if (Request::getProxy()) {
        curl_setopt($r->channel, CURLOPT_PROXY, Request::getProxy());
    }
    curl_setopt($r->channel, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    return $r->channel;
}
```

This is live code, and my `Request` object has as signature the following:

```
protected $headers = array();
protected $baseURI = "";
public $GET = array();
public $POST = array();
```

Running `$result = curl_exec($r->channel);` returns the headers and the body. You can then split them with this:

```
 $header_size = curl_getinfo($r->channel, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
 $headers = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
 $body = substr($result, $header_size);
```

From there, you're free to do whatever you like with `$header` and `$body`. You also get a plethora of info by running curl_getinfo($r->channel).

To parse HTML in PHP, you're better off doing two things first:

- Letting `tidy` loose on it to clear out malformatted mark-up
- Parsing it using `DOMDocument`.

Comment: `Advice is to wrap it in a function` ... like `file_get_contents`, for example.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: with considerably more control. See the example I posted - I have quite a bit more control than `file_get_contents`...in one call.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Who are you to judge? I've stripped out 2/3 of the code present in there as not directly relevant to the question. Not just that, but here's a valid usage - I regularly scrape Google Play, which requires me to go through a proxy to go through their geolocation hoops. `file_get_contents` would simply fail. Finally, instead of throwing venom on just about every answer author on this with nothing more than **rhetoric**...How about you show us the breadth of your wisdom?

Comment: I'm not "judging" anyone, nor have I employed "venom" or "rhetoric". I simply pointed out that, conceivably, you don't need any fine-grained control over the HTTP request. Are you disputing that this will be the case in some scenarios? Also, speaking of "venom", please watch your tone - this is a professional community.

Comment: "And, quite concievably, you need none of it." - this is rhetoric. Facts? None. A baseless call. I have just provided you with a prime example for the finer control that curl offers compared to `file_get_contents`. I'll reiterate: in quite a few situations, you *do* need the finer controls that cURL allows you to use - making PUT requests, tunnelling over proxies, setting user-agents, arbitrary timeouts and manipulating POST body. Sometimes, those are needed. Going by generalizations such as "you need none of it" does nothing for the community. It just pisses people off.

Comment: Well, if you want to try to pretend that there is no person in the world who will ever _just want to make an HTTP request_ without needing to specify proxies or timeouts, then that's your business. However, out here in the real world, sometimes we just want the simplest solution. Really, you're the only one generalising, and "pissing people off" (again, I'll ask you to be _polite_ and _cordial_ please). **(Or, perhaps, you have misunderstood the meaning of the term "conceivably".)**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: cURL is also considerably faster, as another author has pointed out. Nothing prevents you from wrapping curl into a function that will perform exactly the same thing...faster. Finally, "out there in the real world" - was the Google Play example *not* the real world? I can name countless sites that require you to go through hoops one way or another in order to extract data from them.

Comment: I really don't know why you're arguing. All I've said is that there are scenarios that one can conceive of in which this level of fine-grained control is not required. I don't know how to make that clearer to you, and I'm not going to try any more.

Answer (score 1):

For a lot of purposes, a file_get_contents() is sufficient. But there are a lot of cases, where you need special requests.

Using PHP Stream context: Usable if no curl is available and you have to put POST-Data in your request

Curl: The swiss army knife for getting HTTP-Content and usually works best. And there is one special case you should use curl if possible: If you fetch a remote page you own request is blocked. In this case your are dependent on the performance of the remote site. If you are using an webserver like Apache2 with a limited amount of slots, they might fill up if the remote site is too slow or unreachable. I experienced some server downs with cases like this. Curl helps you by setting a timeout for the request. Best to set it low like 3 seconds.

But the best way is to fetch the external content with a cronjob or something like this, caching it and using the cached version.